# What sed syntax should I use on cURL Google API

Tags: curl, sed

I would want to get following data: AAPL

Using sed on the following cURL: `curl -s "http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=AAPL"`

The Google API gives me an XML answer and the tag containing APPL is `<symbol data=""/>` i.e `<symbol data="AAPL"/>`

Is it possible to use one sed to give me the data from 2 XML tags?

Im running MAC OS X 10.8.2 and I'm quite new to Unix bash/shell commands.

Comment: What two tags? What's desired output and sample input? Anyway, the answer is: Yes it is, but `sed` is not the best tool for that. XPath queries would get you the result in a simpler and more reliable way. Have a look at `xmlstarlet` for a command line tool.

Comment: Following 2 XML tags and I would like to only display the data <symbol data="AAPL"/> and <last data="439.88"/>. Lets use sed for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit verbose -- and you'd be able to reduce it using GNU sed -- but this should do the trick:

```
curl -s "http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=AAPL" |
  grep -Eo '<(symbol|last) [^>]*>' |
  sed -e 's/.*data="//' -e 's/".*//'
```

Or in pure `sed` (although a bit brutish):

```
curl -s "http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=AAPL" |
  sed -e 's/.*<symbol data="\([^>]*\)"\/>.*<last data="\([^>]*\)"\/>.*/\1 \2/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) shell command (installed by libxml) and a [Xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath) expression.

Comment: Thanks, will check them out later. But for now I would like to use sed.

Below you have som example output from cURL. I would like to use sed to display the data from these 2 tags; <symbol data="AAPL"/> <last data="439.88"/> 

<?xml version="1.0"?><xml_api_reply version="1"><finance module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0" ><symbol data="AAPL"/><symbol_lookup_url data="/finance?client=ig&amp;q=AAPL"/><company data="Apple Inc."/><exchange data="Nasdaq"/><divisor data="2"/><currency data="USD"/><last data="439.88"/><high data="456.23"/><low data="435.00"/>

Comment: This comment is too long and the output should be part of this or another question, if it's relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Not `sed`. It's a `perl` one-liner split in several lines and using an XML parser, `XML::Twig`:

```
perl-5.14.2 -MXML::Twig -e '
    BEGIN { 
        sub process { printf qq|%s\n|, $_[1]->print } 
    } 
    XML::Twig->new( 
        twig_handlers => { 
            symbol => \&process, 
            last => \&process 
        } 
    )->parse( qx{curl -s "http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=AAPL"} )
'
```

It yields:

```
<symbol data="AAPL"/>
<last data="439.88"/>
```

Comment: But it should be possible to use sed. I just cant fogure out the syntax